# Docker, referencing a different container. Call mysqldump using php command

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I've got a database backup bundle (https://github.com/dizda/CloudBackupBundle) installed on a Symfony3 project using Docker, but I can't get it to work due to it either not finding PHP or not finding MySQL

When I run `php app/console --env=prod dizda:backup:start` via exec, run, or via cron. I get mysqldump command not found error through the PHP image, or PHP not found error from the Mysql/db image.

How do I go about running a php command that then runs a mysqldump command.

My docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        # image: nginx:latest
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
        links:
            - php
            - db
            - node
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    php:
        # image: php:fpm
        restart: always
        build: ./docker_setup/php
        links:
            - redis
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
          - "/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8001:3306
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: gfxhae671
          MYSQL_DATABASE: boxstat_db_live
          MYSQL_USER: boxstat_live
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: GfXhAe^7!
    node:
        # image: //digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt:5
        build: ./docker_setup/node
        volumes_from:
            - php
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
```

I'm pretty new to docker, so and easy improvements you can see feel free t flag...I'm in the trial and error stage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image that has your code should have all the dependencies needed for your code to run.

In this case, your code needs mysqldump installed locally for it to run. I would consider this to be a dependency of your code.

It might make sense to add a RUN line to your Dockerfile that will install the mysqldump command so that your code can use it.

Another approach altogether would be to externalize the database backup process instead of leaving that up to your application. You could have some container that runs on a cron and does the mysqldump process that way.

I would consider both approaches to be clean.

Comment: my db image already has mysqldump installed though, can't I use that somehow or do I have to install it again?

Comment: containers, by design, provide isolation from eachother. You'll definitely want your image to have everything it needs installed there, despite other containers/images also having it.

Comment: And if he installs mysql dump in the php container, is it possible to make a mysql dump from a remote database?

Comment: yes. mysqldump is just a mysql client, and can connect to a remote database.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MySQL client in your PHP container via Dockerfile as follow:

Dockerfile :

```
...
# install default-mysql-client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client && rm -rf /var/lib/apt
...
```

Then, use the following command (in your controller) to generate the backup:

```
mysql -u root --password=DB_PASSWORD -h mysql /usr/bin/mysqldump your-mysql-container-name > storage/app/backups/backup_filename.sql;
```

I hope this helps someone!